# String operation on Series

Tags: python, pandas

The series given below shows the estimated population for each country.

Here is the **'PopEst' Series:**

```
Country
China                 1367645161.29
United States         317615384.615
Japan                 127409395.973
United Kingdom        63870967.7419
Russian Federation      143500000.0
Canada                35239864.8649
Germany               80369696.9697
India                 1276730769.23
France                63837349.3976
South Korea           49805429.8643
Italy                 59908256.8807
Spain                 46443396.2264
Iran                  77075630.2521
Australia              23316017.316
Brazil                205915254.237
Name: PopEst, dtype: object
```

I want to convert the values in the above series to strings and want to add a thousands seperator (using commas).

Ex - 317615384.61538464 -> 317,615,384.61538464

I converted the above series to string using

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

However, I don't know how to proceed ahead.

Comment: I know comments are used to ask for clarification but thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: added to dupe answer.